# Are cold showers or contrast showers better for recovery?

Tags: cold

Nearly every day in the morning, I get up and have a 5 min cold shower. I've heard of contrast showers before, but never tried one (I was too repulsed). I'm relatively adapted (6 months of 5 days a week) and impressed with my increase in recovery time. This is specifically for strength training recovery.

I was wondering if contrast (cold/hot/cold/hot...) showers would bring better recovery now. If so, what protocol to use?